# Python: Importing basic packages inside packages

Tags: python

I made a package that needs to import other packages like pandas and numpy. Here is the basic dir structure:

```
main.py

my_pkg/
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

test.py contains something like this (I do not import anything)

```
def function():
    foo=pd.read_csv(....)
```

I tried doing this in main.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from my_pkg import test

test.function()
```

But I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

How do I import pandas and numpy so that `test.function()` is able to use them?

Comment: Have you tried importing those modules in the module that uses them, i.e. `test.py`?

Comment: `main.py` does not use pandas or numpy, so those imports are useless.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing Pandas in main.py it is out of scope of the function `function`.

You should import Pandas in test.py itself so that the function can use it.

Answer (score 0):

- It's good practice to import relevant libraries/packages in the file where they are primarily using.[ but `from my_pkg.test import function` adds `function` into current variable scope.]
- Define all the libraries/packages essential to run your libraries in the `setup.py` file under `install_requires` key. Do not include libraries/packages used for **test** & **build** specially.